# Can I use <%= ... %> to set a control property in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" CssClass="formField" MaxLength="<%=Constants.MaxCharacterLengthOfGameName %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The code above does not work. I can set the MaxLength property of the textbox in the code behind but i rather not. Is there away I can set the MaxLength property in the front-end code as above?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid code-behind?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use DataBinding:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="tbName" 
    CssClass="formField" 
    MaxLength="<%# Constants.MaxCharacterLengthOfGameName %>" 
    runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

and in your code behind Page_Load call:

```
tbName.DataBind();
```

or directly databind the page:

```
this.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 6):

The <%= expression %> syntax is translated into Response.Write(expression), injecting the value of expression into the page's rendered output. Because <%= expression %> is translated into (essentially) a Response.Write these statements cannot be used to set the values of Web control properties. **In other words, you cannot have markup like the following:**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="CurrentTime" Text="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" />
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513211719/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Try to use custom expression builder:

```
// from http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx
[ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
public class CodeExpressionBuilder : System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilder
{
    public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry,
       object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context)
    {
        return new CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" CssClass="formField" MaxLength="<%$ Code: Constants.MaxCharacterLengthOfGameName %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: +1. Note that the value of the ExpressionBuilder is evaluated *once* so it is good for constants, bad for a lot of other things.

Comment: +1 This is actually a great solution, you don't bloat the viewstate with it. I forgot all about this feature.

Answer (score 4):

As Ropstah said, it isn't going to work with the <%= expression %> syntax.

But you could probably use databinding, which just requires that you use the <%# expression %> syntax and then call MyTextBox.Databind in CodeBehind.

Of course, at that point it might be more clear to just do the whole operation in CodeBehind.

Another alternative: if you really want this to be declarative, you could get away from the Label and embed your expression in a span tag.That way you still get to apply CSS, etc and I think the <%= expression %> syntax would work.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just set it in the Page_Init callback function in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to be able to control the max length of a specific type of text box from a single location so that if that max length needs to change, you only need to change it in one place.

You can accomplish this by using a skin file.  You set the max length in the skin file as you would normally and then any textbox that uses that max length would use the skin.  If the length changes then you only need to change the skin file.

Answer (score 1):

This example is geared towards getting the max length from underlying sql types in linq. But you should be able to customise it to your needs

http://blog.binaryocean.com/2008/02/24/TextBoxMaxLengthFromLINQMetaData.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with databinding

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="tbName" 
    CssClass="formField" 
    MaxLength='<%# Constants.MaxCharacterLengthOfGameName %>' 
    runat="server" />
```

Then in the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can embed "normal" code in the .aspx file if you so want, like:

```
<%
tbName.MaxLength = Constants.MaxCharacterLengthOfGameName
%>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" CssClass="formField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This harkens back to an older style "classic" ASP way of doing this.