# Render DateTime.Now directly in the ASPX page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do the following directly into the aspx page but it is not showing the date value. I dont want to do it from the code behind. Am i missing something small here? Pls suggest.

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrDate" Text='<% DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Even the use of hash in the expression <%#DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %> does not work.

Comment: Have you tried it this way ? <% Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());%>

Comment: So what *is* it showing?

Comment: i tried <asp:Literal ID="ltrDate" Text='<%Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());%>'. But it didn't work. It is showing empty..

Comment: must it be a Literal? can't you use a Label ?

Comment: i am curious to know how we can call the server side code directly into the ASPX without the need of using the code behind.. There is something which is stopping it from rendering this way...That is why i was thinking of using the <% %> to inject the server side code..

Comment: Please see this question for different ways you can accomplish what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362771/can-i-use-to-set-a-control-property-in-asp-net. You cannot use Response.Write or <%= %> in properties of server controls.

Comment: If you do not actually need to access this date value from the code-behind, then just skip the literal control, and type the following directly into your page where you want it to display: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>

Comment: Writing the expression outside the literal works!.. But do you know the reason why its not working inside the literal..

Comment: Because the only thing you can put inside the properties of server controls are static text or databinding expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a databinding expression such as `<%# DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>`, then you have to call `Page.DataBind()` (or `ltrDate.DataBind()` if that's the only databound control) from your code-behind (e.g. in Page_Load).

Answer (score 18):

If you do not need to access the value of the Literal control from the code-behind, then there is no need to use it. Instead, you can just use the following expression in your page directly where you want to print the date:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
```

With server controls, you can only put either static text, databinding expressions `<%# xx %>`, or expression builders `<%$ %>` inside the property values in the page markup.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362771/can-i-use-to-set-a-control-property-in-asp-net) for more details about each approach.