# How to set an enum value to a custom property of a web user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How do we bind an enum value to the property of a web user control? I keep receiving this error.

> Cannot create an object of type 'MyEnum' from its string representation 'MyEnum.MyValue' for the 'MyProperty' property.

This is the code behind MyWebUserControl.ascx.cs

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
```

SomeWebUserControl.ascx

```
<!-- This fails -->
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server" ID="MyControl1"
    MyProperty="MyEnum.MyValue" />

<!-- This fails -->
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server" ID="MyControl2" 
    MyProperty="<%# MyEnum.MyValue %>" />

<!-- This works -->
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server" ID="MyControl3"
    MyProperty="0" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defining the property on the control is easy, as you have done:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
```

However, it's worth noting that the `[Bindable(true)]` attribute isn't needed. It's just there as a hint for VS to offer additional databinding properties in the property grid. It doesn't affect the ASP.NET runtime at all.

To set this property statically in the ASPX markup, just use the enum's *value*:

```
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server"
    ID="MyControl1"
    MyProperty="MyValue" />
```

If you want to set it dynamically, you can do it in `Page_Init`:

```
void Page_Init() {
    MyControl1.MyProperty = GetEnumValueFromSomewhere();
}

<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server"
    ID="MyControl1" />
```

And finally, to set it dynamically as part of databinding, you can use the `<%# foo %>` databinding syntax:

```
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server"
    ID="MyControl1"
    MyProperty="<%# GetEnumValueFromSomewhere() %>" />
```

Note that the databinding option should be used *only when databinding*. If you're not trying to do databinding, it is rather wasteful to call `DataBind()` on the entire page, or even just on that one control.

Comment: If we just use a `MyValue` string instead of using the `enum`, then what happens when we refactor? I'd rather put `MyEnum.MyValue` into the property so that compilation or something similar breaks if we refactor out the `MyValue` from the `enum`.

Comment: It's using the real enum value, it's not a string. Your code won't compile or run if the enum value changes.

Comment: Specifically, you'll get an error like this: `Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'MyEnumType' from its string representation 'SomeBadValue' for the 'MyProperty' property.`

Answer (score 0):

This workaround might help solve the issue. You can tie the "real" property to a string property like so:

```
private MyEnum _MyProperty = MyEnum.Default;

[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public MyEnum MyProperty
{
    get {
        return _MyProperty;
    }
    set {
        _MyProperty = value;
    }
}

public string MyPropertyString 
{
    get {
        return _MyProperty.ToString();
    }
    set {
        _MyProperty = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse( typeof(MyEnum), value, true );
    }
}
```

And use 'MyPropertyString` on the control. It's not an elegant solution, but it may do the trick. Seems like there HAS to be a better answer than this, but I looked around and was not able to find anything yet.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem in question. The scenario involved databinding, which this answer doesn't address.

Comment: @Eilon I think you are correct. I will most likely delete this answer as it appears Shaun  has found the correct one. No reason to clutter the thread with a workaround that may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

## `Page.DataBind()`

- `Page.DataBind()` is necessary - that's what was missing.
- `[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]` is NOT necessary on the property.

## Example

MyWebUserControl.ascx.cs

```
public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
```

SomeWebUserControl.ascx

```
<uc1:MyWebUserControl runat="server" ID="MyControl" 
    MyProperty="<%# MyEnum.MyValue %>" />
```

SomeWebUserControl.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is 100% necessary to bind enum
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

See also: [Render DateTime.Now directly in the ASPX page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876812/render-datetime-now-directly-in-the-aspx-page)

Comment: Downvote was me, I was busy typing an answer. The issue here is that databinding the entire page isn't quite the ideal solution. It's certainly possible, and it will work, but there are many other options. Given that the value is static, databinding is not needed at all.

Comment: I actually edited the title of your question earlier as well, though looking at the question again I think my edit may have even been premature. Are you truly trying to databind, or do you just want to set the property to a static value? Apologies for my confusion.

Comment: @Eilon I would just like to set the property to the value of an enum. My example is more accurate than the words that I used to indicate what I'm trying to achieve. Also, I would rather use the enum than a string just in case we refactor the enum.

Comment: My example shows how to use the enum value. There are no string used at all. The error in the example in your question is that the enum's type name can't be used. Just set `MyProperty="TheEnumValue"` and ASP.NET will do the right thing.